# Как сделать исключение в CSS в данном случае?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть код CSS и HTML:

```css
article {
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

hr {
 background-color: #000;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Мой текст</p>
    <hr>
</article>
```

Проблема в том, что я не хочу использовать `margin-left: 5px` для `hr`, который находится в самом `article`. Я пытался сделать так:

```
article:not(hr) {......}
```

Но это не работает. Что ещё можно сделать?

Comment: `article hr { margin-left: 0; }`

Comment: hr { margin-left: 5px; } и article hr { margin-left: 0px; }.  upd: как можно обрамлять текст в код подобно комментарию выше? Не нашел внятной документации по markdown.

Comment: это мне не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)обычно подобные декоративные элементы делаются с помощью псевдоэлементов.

2)Исходя из вышесказанного нельзя оценить ваш навык правильно, так что если укажу на то что вы знаете ,прошу прощения.

В этом случае для "балансировки" плохим, на мой взгляд , вариантом будет играться с маргинами, тут же стоит применить к **hr** следующее:

`hr {
  transform: translateX(-5px);
}`

Что как мне кажется будет профессиональнее.

Так же имеет смысл просто вынести hr за пределы article и не морочить голову, но еще лучше будет вовсе убрать hr и воспользоваться 1) пунктом!

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете компенсировать смещение вправо, сместив сам тег `<hr>` влево, добавив к нему свойства

```
hr {
    ...
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
}
```

```css
article {
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

hr {
 background-color: #000;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <p>Мой текст</p>
    <hr>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
article hr {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, и чем же он неподробный?

Comment: ответ был бы «чуть более развёрнутым» при наличии объяснения. о том, что ответ, скорее всего, не очень хорош, даже движок [как бы намекает](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51003042#51003042).

Answer (score 0):

```css
hr { margin-left: 5px; }
article hr { margin-left: 0px; }
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Мой текст</p>
    <hr>
</article>

Без article:
 <hr>
 <hr>
 <hr>
```